# PHPSecLib Net_SFTP Slow Transfer

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I am using Net_SFTP / phpseclib to upload files to a remote SFTP server. When uploading the test file from the sftp command line I average about 50Mbps. When uploading the same files from and to the same servers using PHPSecLib Net_SFTP I am only able to achieve about 17.0Mbps transfer rate.

Here is the code I am using for the transfer. I checked and there does not appear to be any CPU usage / networking bottle neck for the transfer. Any ideas on how to get the transfer rate up?

Note that I am using PHP version 5.6 and the newest version of phpseclib that I just downloaded from their site. I also verified that mcrypt is enabled via phpinfo().

Also running $sftp->getServerIdentification() results in

```
SSH-2.0-9.99 sshlib: 8.1.0.0
```

When connecting to the SFTP Server.

Here is the test code that only results in 17Mbps...

```
$port = 22;
$host = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$user = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$pass = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$sftp = new Net_SFTP($host, $port);
if (!$sftp->login($user, $pass)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$localFile = '000000.pdf'; //This is about a 300Mb test file
$ftpFile = '/Account/Testing/0000000.pdf';

$ftpResult = $sftp->put($ftpFile, $localFile, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
$sftp->disconnect();
```

Comment: The speed will depend on the encryption algorithms being used. TripleDES, for example, is slower than RC4 or AES. That said, you may have better success with the master branch. In particular, https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/pull/945 . That pull request appears to be merged in the master branch but not in any of the other branches.

Comment: Looks like they implemented the parallel download for the get() function but not the put() function.

Comment: In the 1.0 and 2.0 branches that appears to be correct. I'll see if I can get that feature into the 1.0 and 2.0 branches tho but I'll need to make the code changes, submit a pull request, etc.